# Is it grammatically and semantically correct to use "didn't much like" as a phrase?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Does "didn't much like" accurately express the idea that the writer did not like it as much as she would have desired.  Would it be actually wrong, or would it be better if it is expressed as "didn't like it much".

> I didn’t much like ongoing conversations among the group of people I interacted with.

is the sentence that intrigued me

Is it correct to write "didn’t much like" I am not sure but the word much seems redundant and in some ways trying to measure something non-measurable?  I did see that a few bloggers have used this in their articles, but not entirely sure if it's sufficiently authoritative to consider correct.

Comment: Try to provide some illustrative sentences to parse.

Comment: *Didn't much (verb)* as in *didn't much care* is a common enough construction. https://ludwig.guru/s/didn%27t+much+like https://ludwig.guru/s/didn%27t+much+care

Comment: "I didn’t much like ongoing conversations among the group of people I interacted with" is the sentence that intrigued me

Comment: Thanks for the website - nice tool for me and others to use

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are wanting to say 1) you didn't like it as much as you expected to like it (but you did still like it to some extent); or (2) you actually rather disliked it.  In British English, "didn't much like" is a polite way of saying "didn't like"!

Comment: Idiomatically, English speakers tend not to use "much like" (where "like" is a verb) in affirmative expressions (as in  "I much like that guy"), although many English speakers do commonly use it in negative expressions (as in "I don't much like that guy"), where the meaning is much like that of a negative form of "like very much" (as in "I don't like that guy very much"), which, in contrast, is often used in affirmative expressions (as in "I like that guy very much"). It's a strange language.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: "I didn't much like" is a common expression, but informal.

Comment: @SvenYargs: On the other hand, while we don't say "I much like [sth]" we often do say "I very much like [sth]" ... and yes, it's a strange language.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt from recent searches that didn't much like is acceptable as it qualifies the liking.  Another form that is commonly found in usage is didn't particularly like.